# Using string functions to indicate member of an enumeration in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, enums

I have to copy some data from one table to another. There are several groups of columns that are the same except for a name at the start of the column header.  I want to put those names into an array, and then loop through the groups doing the same operations on each group. I'd like to do this using an enumeration of the headers, but I can't find a way to reference the members of the enumeration by concatenating the name and the remainder of the header.  Boiling it down to the essentials, the code would look like this:

```
Enum Headers
a1 = 1
b1
c1
End Enum

Sub test()
Dim Pick() As Variant
Pick = Array("a", "b", "c")
For i = 1 To 3
    n = Headers.Concat(Pick(i), "1")
    MyTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(Row, n) = OtherTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(Row, n)
Next i
End Sub
```

I know how to work around this, using a slightly different approach, and that's what I think I'll end up doing.

```
MyTable.ListColumns(Pick(i) & "1").DataBodyRange.Cells(Row,0)
```

That works because the column reference is to a string, so I can piece the string together in that fashion.

But I wanted to know if anyone has a way to use something akin to what I outlined above using an enumeration.

Comment: In your pseudo code, is n supposed to be a string or an integer?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing and your code does not do much to clarify. Maybe include a small example of the source table headers and the destination table headers and try to explain a little more clearly how to get from one to the other?

Comment: I guess I should have added a comment, but my response is posted as an answer.

Comment: n is supposed to end up being the value of a1, b1 or c1 in the enumeration, so it should end up being 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 0):

n is the value of the enumeration member, so it could be 1, 2, or 3.
This would be the column where I want to copy or paste data. The row would be "Row", so the reference is to Cells(Row, n).

Instead of specifying the member as a1, b1 or c1, I want to use an expression Concat(Pick(i), "1"), where Pick(i) will be "a", "b", or "c".

Both tables would have headers a1, b1, c1.

The problem is that
`n = Headers.Concat(Pick(i), "1")`
but
`n = Headers.a1`
would be valid.  I just can't substitute Concat(Pick(i) for a1, since a "valid VB identifier" is required following "Headers.", not a string.
is not a valid statement.

My question is whether there is some way to accomplish what the invalid code is trying to do. Sort of like an indirect reference in Excel, where you can turn a string into a range or file reference.